# What is the fastest way to determine if a table spans two pages?

Tags: vba, ms-word

The initial problem that led me to learn VBA is as follows:

You have a table that can be up to 10,000 rows (several hundred pages) long in a Word document. The table has a title in the form of a paragraph above the first row. This title is styled such that it links to a Table of Contents (`Style = "Caption"`). The table must be broken at the last row on each page, and the title must be inserted before the new table but in a different style that is not linked to the Table of Contents(`Style = "Caption Cont"`).

The first page will look like this:[image: linked to the ToC]

The second page will look like this: [image: not linked to ToC]

My first solution was relatively hackey and not at all elegant. I've managed to put together the following solution that works quite well. However, the initial process of determining the row number at which the table crosses pages is pretty slow due to the use of `Range.Information`. I'm wondering if there's a faster way to determine the bottom row on the page.

Putting the document into `wdNormalView` shaves off about a second per page, even with `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`...

The program requires that your cursor is somewhere inside the table, which is fine and not a functionality I wish to remove.

It currently does about 120 pages per minute, with the majority of the time being spent on determining the row to split at (i.e. `splitNum`). I'm sure it can be much faster with a different method of determining `splitNum`.

**I CANNOT ADD AN ADDITIONAL ROW TO THE TABLE FOR THE PURPOSES OF USING "REPEAT HEADER ROWS".** 
It would violate regulations that are enforced in my industry, and a non-conforming document can be a huge hit to the company and future business. This code is meant as a standalone and should not require that users alter their workflow.

Code:

```vb
Sub tblSplit()

Dim timeCheck As Double

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.ActiveWindow.View = wdNormalView

timeCheck = Time

On Error GoTo ErrH

Dim crossRef As Range, delRange As Range, tblR As Range, newTbl As Range
Dim tblNumField As Range, tblNum As String

Set tblNumField = Selection.Tables(1).Range
tblNumField.MoveStart wdParagraph, -1
tblNum = tblNumField.Words(2)


Set crossRef = Selection.Tables(1).Range
Set thisTbl = Selection.Tables(1).Rows(1).Range
Set tblR = Selection.Tables(1).Range
```

Insert cross-reference to title with style "Caption Cont"

```vb
crossRef.Move wdCharacter, -2
crossRef.InsertCrossReference ReferenceType:="Table", ReferenceKind:= _
        wdOnlyCaptionText, ReferenceItem:=tblNum, InsertAsHyperlink:=True, _
        IncludePosition:=False, SeparateNumbers:=False, SeparatorString:=" "
crossRef.Text = vbCr & " (Cont.)" & vbTab


crossRef.MoveStart wdCharacter, 1
crossRef.Style = "Caption Cont."
crossRef.Collapse wdCollapseStart

crossRef.InsertCrossReference ReferenceType:="Table", ReferenceKind:= _
        wdOnlyLabelAndNumber, ReferenceItem:=tblNum, InsertAsHyperlink:=True, _
        IncludePosition:=False, SeparateNumbers:=False, SeparatorString:=" "
crossRef.MoveEnd wdParagraph, 1
```

Delete duplicate title

```vb
Set delRange = crossRef.Duplicate

crossRef.MoveEnd wdParagraph, 1
crossRef.Copy
delRange.Text = vbNullString
```

**Find row at which table spans two pages**

```vb
Dim splitNum As Long, n As Long, i As Long, pageNum As Long
pageNum = tblR.Rows(1).Range.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber)
i = 15
    Do
       If tblR.Rows(i).Next.Range.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber) <> pageNum Then
            splitNum = i
            Exit Do

        End If
        i = i + 1
    Loop Until i = 100 'arbitrary cap to prevent infinite loop

n = 1
```

Split and format

```vb
Do
    DoEvents


    'Split and format
    tblR.Tables(n).Split (splitNum)
    tblR.Tables(n).Rows.Last.Borders(wdBorderBottom).LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle

    'Paste the stuff
    Set newTbl = tblR.Tables(n + 1).Range
    newTbl.Move wdParagraph, -2
    newTbl.Paste
    newTbl.MoveEnd wdParagraph, 1
    'Clear excess
    newTbl.Paragraphs.Last.Range.Text = vbNullString

    'Next
    n = n + 1
Loop Until tblR.Tables(n).Rows.Count < splitNum
```

Restore state, report time, safe-exit and error handler set-up for debugging

```vb
Application.ActiveWindow.View = wdPrintView
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox "Pages completed: " & n & vbCr & _
    "Time (sec): " & DateDiff("s", timeCheck, Time) & vbCr & _
    "Seconds per page: " & CDbl(DateDiff("s", timeCheck, Time)) / CDbl(n) & vbCr & _
    "Pages per minute: " & n / DateDiff("s", timeCheck, Time) * 60


Exit Sub

ErrH:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Err.Raise Err.Number
    Stop

End Sub
```